# Two (or more) socket client connections on one machine

Tags: sockets, tcp, node.js

I have a simple node.js client and server programs running on one machine and when I try to connect to the server with second instance of client program simultaneously I get `EADDRINUSE, Address already in use` error. Is it possible to have two or more TCP based socket client connections (created with [createConnection](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/net.html#net.createConnection)) to one server (created with [createServer](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/net.html#net.createServer)) on the same machine, or only one client program can be connected to the server at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Infact, **very** common. Many applications open dozens, or hundreds of connections to the same server. It sounds like your client program is binding on a port. Only the server should be binding on a port. You should verify.

The client will usually use a random port between 1024-65535, as assigned by your OS. You don't need to worry about it. Since the client is initiating a connection to the server, the server port must unique to one program. Which is why your problem signifies you are trying to start the server twice. Please see http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPClientEphemeralPortsandClientServerApplicatio.htm